# Batch get last char of %%A

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a variable in my batch file that contains the path to the "newest" folder on my share folder.
Each folder on that share folder has a version number at the end i.e.: "product_1.0.0.1".

My approach was to iterate though the parent folder and check the last chars of the subdirectories for which number is the highest.

```
set latest=\\Share\prod\1.0\tools\prod_1.0.0.0
for /d %%A in ("\\Share\prod\1.0\tools") do 
  if %%A:~1 gtr %latest:~1% 
    (set latest=%%A)
```

This does not work since it does not seem to get the last char `%%A`

Another problem that appears on my mind on writing this question is how do i handle numbers greater than 9?
As I understand `:~1` gets the last char, so a better approach may be to get everything behind the last dot. How would i do that?

Comment: You'll need to enable delayed expansion.  See `setlocal /?` and `help set` in a cmd console for full details.  You'll need to `set "var=%%~A"` then `if !var:~-1! gtr %latest:~-1%`.  The `%%~A` is more an iterator than a variable, and cannot be used directly for substring extractions or substitutions.  However, it's easy enough to set a %variable% to the value of `%%~A`.  Also, if you're comparing Major.Minor.Build.Revision version data, this would be much easier in PowerShell by casting as a `System.Version` object.  You could compare numerically without having to split or use substrings.

Comment: @rojo this bat is not part of the build. it's more of an easy way to get some binaries and needed data from the build drop folder to the guys working with it so that they won't need to search for the latest folder and "guess" which files the need. but thanks on the clarification on `%%A` i thought it would work more like in a typical for each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dir /ad /oe /b "\\Share\prod\1.0\tools"`. The option `/ad` means "list only directories (folders)", the option `/oe` means "Order by extension", and `/b` means "Bare output" (just the names). The extension is everything after the last dot. You can then put that in a loop and set `latest` to each result, and the variable will get the last result. Or use the option `/o-e` ("Order by extension in reverse order") and then break out of the loop after the first iteration:

```
set latest=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /o-e /b "\\Share\prod\1.0\tools"') do (
    set latest=%%a
    goto exit1
)
:exit1
```

The problem with the above is what to do when the numbers go beyond 9. You can work around that by naming them product_1.0.0.001, product_1.0.0.002, etc.